# DNA Dead skin cells

Tags: human-anatomy

If the stratum corneum is anucleated, dead cells - how is it that we are able to get DNA from buccal cheek swabs? Are we grabbing more than just the stratum corneum with the swab (eg. the underlying cells that are nucleated)?

Comment: I'm curious: does the inside of your cheek feel anything like the palm of your hand?

Comment: Thanks! I just read that the inner cheek is one of the places in the mouth with nonkeratinized squamous epithelium. So the cells we collect with buccal swabs are not of the dry cornified type and retain their nuclei. And the stratum corneum and granulosum are absent from this lining mucosa.

Answer (score 2):

Because our buccal cavity is not covered by skin but by [oral mucosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_mucosa) (nucleated [epithelial cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithelium)).

Comment: Why the down votes?